# Free and fast GUI builder for desktop application

Tags: user-interface, desktop-application

I'm working on Desktop Application for commercial purposes, It was implemented in Swing/Java but it was too slow, so my manager asked me to re-implement it in different GUI frame work that is free and fast enough, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specify a language/technology, I suggest using the flex framework in flash.  There exists a lot of technologies in flex that integrate very well with java.  Its development environment is also very similar.  Here are some java-inspired libraries/frameworks (as an example):

- flex-mojos
- blaze-ds/granite-ds
- spring actionscript
- flexUnit
- flexmonkey (selenium)

While flash has a generally bad rep when it comes to consumer (in recent years), I believe it is very strong on the commercial side for tooling.  When it comes to the UI, however, very few things beat it.  I know a lot of companies still use flex front end + java back end.